# PHP - How can I find pull out only the integers in a string that separates the integers with two periods?

Tags: php, string, strip

Say I have a string like this:

```
$string = '.30..5..12..184..6..18..201..1.'
```

How would I pull out each of the integers, stripping the periods, and store them into an array?

Answer (score 3):

You could use this. You break the string up by all of the periods... but this only works if it is exactly like that; if there is other stuff in the middle for example 25.sdg.12 it wouldnt work.

```
    <?php
    $my_array = explode("..",$string);
    $my_array[0] = trim($my_array[0]); //This removes the period in first part making '.30' into '30'
  ///XXX  $my_array[-1] = trim($my_array[-1]); XXX If your string is always the same format as that you could just use 7 instead.
```

I checked and PHP doesn't support negative indexes but you can count the array list and just use that. Ex:

```
$my_index = count($my_array) - 1;
$my_array[$my_index] = trim($my_array[$my_index]); //That should replace '1.' with '1' no matter what format or length your string is.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will break up your string into an array and then loop through to grab numbers.

```
$string = '.30..5..12..184..6..18..201..1.';
$pieces = explode('.', $string);

foreach($pieces as $key=>$val) {
    if( is_numeric($val) ) {
    $numbers[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Your numbers will be in the array `$numbers`

Comment: @Steve-o You're free to post your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

All I could think of.

```
<?php
$string = '.30..5..12..184..6..18..201..1.';
$r_string = str_replace("..", ",", $string);
$r_string = str_replace(".", ",", $r_string);
print_r(explode(",", $r_string));
?>
```

Or If you want to the array in a variable

```
<?php
$string = '.30..5..12..184..6..18..201..1.';
$r_string = str_replace("..", ",", $string);
$r_string = str_replace(".", ",", $r_string);
$arr_ex = explode(",", $r_string);
print_r($arr_ex);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone else posted this but then removed their code, it works as intended:

```
<?php
$string = '.30..5..12..184..6..18..201..1.';

$numbers = array_filter (explode ('.', $string), 'is_numeric');

print_r ($numbers);
?>
```

Output:

> ```
> Array (
> [1] => 30
> [3] => 5
> [5] => 12
> [7] => 184
> [9] => 6
> [11] => 18
> [13] => 201
> [15] => 1 )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
$string = '.30..5..12..184..6..18..201..1.';
$new_string =str_replace(".", "",  str_replace("..", ",", $string));
print_r (explode(",",$new_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
print_r(explode("..",substr($string,1,-1)));
```